# Creating an unmodifiable 2d array in c++

Tags: c++, arrays

Quick background, I have some experience with java and currently new to c++.

My question comes from an assignment in which we had to create 4 different magic squares, but for the nature of this particular question they can be any 2d array, so long as they are "exact" in values, only that they appear differently from each one. What I mean by that is if one 2d array looked like:

1 2 3
4 5 6
7 8 9

the next one would be rotated 90 degrees

7 4 1
8 5 2
9 6 3

and so on..

To make the first matrix I simply made a 2d array and created it using the magic square algorithm (irrelevant)

```
int** square = new int*[size]();
for (int i = 0; i<size; i++) {
   square[i] = new int[size]();
}
//set values to square .. irrelevant to show, could be anything

//way down the code
int** secondSquare = square;
```

For the second third and fourth ones all I would need to do is rotate the previous one to get the next rotated square. My problem however wasn't that I could not flip the arrays, but that while trying to flip them the values for the first square were also changing.

Obviously this is more of a problem about being able to access the data in square and not change it while trying to add them to secondSquare.

I tried making it so square was a modifiable pointer w constant unmodifiable values.

```
const int** square = new int*[size];
```

The problem with this is that I have to assign values after to square so this cannot be done. Also when I initialize secondSquare it gives me an error since it is of type int** and not const int**.

Any better ways to handle problems with accessing data without changing values and setting both arrays (or objects really) properly on initialization?

Comment: You need to allocate another `new int*[size];` and *copy* the values from the previous square into this new square. Better to use a standard C++ container or at least smart pointers.

Comment: If all you do is print them out, then don't create new arrays.  Just print them out by scanning one array in the four different orders.

Comment: It may be better to use a one-dimensional array internally, and view it as a 2D array when necessary.  With 3 items per row (and thus arrays size `[3][3]` or `[9]`), for example, any entity at `(r, c)` in a 2D array would be at `(r * 3) + c` in a 1D array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would do well to avoid using raw pointers and `new` entirely . That should really come in the advanced section of any C++ course.

Here is one way:

```
array< array<int,3>, 3> square = {{ {1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}, {7, 8, 9} }};
square[1][1] = 12;   // optional

const auto &c_square = square;
```

Now `c_square` is a const accessor of `square` that you can use later and avoid risk of modifying `square`.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is `int** secondSquare = square;` copies the address of the `square` pointer to `secondSquare`. So in the end you have two (three, four) pointers pointing to exact same place in memory. Think about it like you have one square created but you try to access it through four different pointers.

What you want to do is to allocate memory for 4 different int** pointers.

Answer (score 0):

To create a 2d array, you would declare it as const:

```
const int array_2d[3][3] =
{
  0, 1, 2,
  3, 4, 5,
  6, 7, 8
};
```

In my experience, the better method is to declare it as `static const` so you are telling the compiler that there is only 1 read only instance:

```
static const int array_2d[3][3] =
{
  0, 1, 2,
  3, 4, 5,
  6, 7, 8
};
```

The `static` allows for the compiler to place the data in a read-only section of the executable and access it directly, rather than copying it from Read-Only to the stack before usage (I've seen compilers emit this kind of code).

Comment: I see how this makes the most sense for a 2d array with values we want to make constant from the beginning. In the assignment I could not have done it this way but can see how static in this case would be more useful.

Comment: -Just so I can get a better understanding of the subject and why that method is better,      so you are saying it is better to declare it static and have a private section where it is read because otherwise, by copying to the stack for usage, it is inefficient or it will be omitted?

Comment: The most efficient method is to access the array directly instead of accessing a copy on the stack.  Code it both ways and compare the assembly language.  Copying is always less efficient than accessing the data directly.